# Updating the google spreedsheet from MS SQL using Google Scripts

Tags: sql, sql-server, jdbc, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to connect the MS SQL to a google spreadsheet using google app scripts. here is my app script code

```
function SQLdb() {
 // Replace the variables in this block with real values.

// Read up to 1000 rows of data from the table and log them.
function readFromTable() {
  var user = '{usename}';
  var userPwd = '{password}';
  var database = '{databasename}'
  var connectionString = 'jdbc:sqlserver://server.database.windows.net:1433;databaseName='+database;
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(connectionString , user, userPwd);

  var start = new Date();
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  stmt.setMaxRows(1000);
  var results = stmt.executeQuery('SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM dbo.dbo');
  var numCols = results.getMetaData().getColumnCount();

  while (results.next()) {
    var rowString = '';
    for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
      rowString += results.getString(col + 1) + '\t';
    }
    Logger.log(rowString)
  }

  results.close();
  stmt.close();

  var end = new Date();
  Logger.log('Time elapsed: %sms', end - start);
 }
 readFromTable();
}
```

Now when I look the log in Script Editor, I can see that this connection to the SQL database is working and the script is able to read all the table cell. But I couldn't able to get that data into the spreedsheet. I'm new to app scripts. So is there something that I'm missing here ?

Any help would be much appricated!

Comment: code shows no attempt at using a spreadsheet. look at the documentation for SprradsheetApp.

Comment: I'm trying to create this script for a spreadsheet which already exists and just trying to get the data from SQL and insert into it. excuse my basic google scripts knowledge. is there any more information that you can give me on this regard ? Thank you!

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it. Change all the capitalised bits to the appropriate URL, database name, Google Spreadsheet ID, etc.

To this function pass the SQL  query you want to execute on the MSSQL database and the name of the sheet within the Spreadsheet that you want to put the data into. This basically fills that named sheet with the query results including column names.

```
function getData(query, sheetName) {
  //jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;user=MyUserName;password=*****;
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://URL;user=USERNAME;password=PASSWORD;databaseName=DBNAME");
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  stmt.setMaxRows(MAXROWS);
  var rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
  Logger.log(rs);

  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SPREADSHEETID");
  var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var results = [];
  var cell = doc.getRange('a1');
  var row = 0;

  cols = rs.getMetaData();
  colNames = [];
  for (i = 1; i <= cols.getColumnCount(); i++ ) {
    Logger.log(cols.getColumnName(i));
    colNames.push(cols.getColumnName(i));
  }
  results.push(colNames);

  var rowCount = 1;
  while(rs.next()) {
    curRow = rs.getMetaData();
    rowData = [];
    for (i = 1; i <= curRow.getColumnCount(); i++ ) {
      rowData.push(rs.getString(i));
    }
    results.push(rowData);
    rowCount++;
  }
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, MAXROWS, cols.getColumnCount()).clearContent();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, rowCount, cols.getColumnCount()).setValues(results);

  Logger.log(results);
  rs.close();
  stmt.close();
  conn.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i did it. I also made a JDBC connector tool for Mysql & MSSQL. You can adapt this tool from my GitHub Repo Here: [Google Spreadsheet JDBC Connector](https://github.com/ebarreat/Google-Spreadsheet-JDBC)

```
function readFromTable(queryType, queryDb, query, tab, startCell) {
  // Replace the variables in this block with real values.
  var address;
  var user;
  var userPwd ;
  var dbUrl;

  switch(queryType) {
    case 'sqlserver':
      address = '%YOUR SQL HOSTNAME%';
      user = '%YOUR USE%';
      userPwd = '%YOUR PW%';
      dbUrl = 'jdbc:sqlserver://' + address + ':1433;databaseName=' + queryDb;
      break;
    case 'mysql':  
      address = '%YOUR MYSQL HOSTNAME%';
      user = '%YOUR USER';
      userPwd = '%YOUR PW%';
      dbUrl = 'jdbc:mysql://'+address + '/' + queryDb;
    break;
  }

  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);
  var start = new Date();
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  var results = stmt.executeQuery(query);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetTab = sheet.getSheetByName(tab);
  var cell = sheetTab.getRange(startCell);
  var numCols = results.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
  var numRows = sheetTab.getLastRow();
  var headers ;
  var row =0;

  clearRange(tab,startCell,numRows, numCols);


  for(var i = 1; i <= numCols; i++){
    headers = results.getMetaData().getColumnName(i);
      cell.offset(row, i-1).setValue(headers);
      }

  while (results.next()) {
    var rowString = '';
    for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
      rowString += results.getString(col + 1) + '\t';
      cell.offset(row +1, col).setValue(results.getString(col +1 ));
    }
    row++
    Logger.log(rowString)
  }

  results.close();
  stmt.close();

  var end = new Date();
  Logger.log('Time elapsed: %sms', end - start);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create your own solution, check out [SeekWell](https://www.seekwell.io/?ref=so). It allows you to connect to databases and write SQL queries directly in Sheets from a sidebar add-on. You can also schedule queries to automatically run daily, hourly or every five minutes.

Disclaimer: I made this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally managed to make it work.
Some few tips: Script is executed at Google's server, so connection must be done over inetrnet, i.e. connect string should be something like "jdbc:sqlserver://172.217.29.206:7000;databaseName=XXXX" and make sure that ip/port mentioned at connect string, can reach you database from outside world. Open port at firewall, make IP forwarding at router and use dyndns or similar services if you do not have a valid domain etc. Sheet ID is the large id string that appeals at your google document's url.